# Sorting array by multiple key values

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

```
foreach(Unit enemy in enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy=>enemy.CurrentHP))
{
    Events.UnitDamaged(enemy);
    return;
}
```

How to pass multiple key values to Sorting? 
Something like

```
enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP && enemy.MaximumHP)
```

Comment: You want to sort by one property and then another?

Comment: do you mean something like `enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP).ThenBy(enemy => enemy.MaximumHP)` ?

Comment: also available: `ThenByDescending`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx):

```
enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP)
       .ThenBy(enemy => enemy.MaximumHP)
```

Or [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx):

```
enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP)
       .ThenByDescending(enemy => enemy.MaximumHP)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP)
       .ThenByDescending(enemy => enemy.MaximumHP)
```

Comment: This will just apply the second sort, and ignore the first one (although, performancewise, it will also do the first one). You need `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending`, methods of the `IOrderedEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enemies.OrderByDescending(enemy => enemy.CurrentHP)
       .ThenByDescending(enemy1 =>  enemy1.MaximumHP)
```