# Sort the list with duplicate values and order according priority tag

Tags: c#, list, sorting, tuples

I have sorted a tuplelist using below code

```
// for loop code
{

list.Add(new Tuple(log[0], "arr"));

list.Add(new Tuple(log[ 1 ], "dep"));
}

// sorts the list

list.Sort((a, b) => a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1));
```

After sorting, It looks like this

[image]

In case of duplicate value, I want to sort list based on tag priority for example 'arr' should have more priority than 'dep'and should come like this

[image]

How can I do this in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add that logic to your comparison:

```
list.Sort((a, b) =>
{
    int result = a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1);

    return result == 0 ? a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2) : result;
});
```

In other words, if the `Item1` properties compare as equal, then compare the `Item2` values and return the result of that instead. Otherwise return the original result.

Note that this example takes advantage of the fact that the value you want to have priority already will naturally sort in the order you want, because lexically `"arr"` comes before `"dep"`.

Using the `Sort()` method is most efficient. But you can improve expressiveness in your code by using LINQ. Something like:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

This will incur additional memory allocations, but to me is much more readable. See [Sorting array by multiple key values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18718071) for more examples.

Comment: What if the they are lexically not prioritized for example instead of "arr" it is  "start" and "dep" is "end".

Comment: @Kanvas: as long as they are _consistently_ ordered, you can just reverse the order. E.g. use `ThenByDescending()` instead of `ThenBy()` or, in the first example, save the `Item2` comparison result before returning it, and return `-1` for positive values and `1` for negative values (do _not_ succumb to the temptation to simply negate the result...the actual comparison can return `int.MinValue` if it wants, and negating that still gives you a negative value, i.e. `int.MinValue` again).